# Cmake on mac os x, link libraries with fullpath

Tags: macos, linker, cmake, rpath, python-extensions

I'm trying to build a python extension with cmake. This is the cmake list:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
PROJECT(drtile)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
find_package(Vigra REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
find_package(Numpy REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    ${VIGRA_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}
)
add_library(drtile SHARED drtile.cpp)
message("xxx ${Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY} ${VIGRA_NUMPY_CORE_LIBRARY}${VIGRA_NUMPY_IMPEX_LIBRARY}")
target_link_libraries(drtile ${Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY} ${VIGRA_NUMPY_CORE_LIBRARY}  ${PYTHON_LIBRARY})
IF(WIN32)
   SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(drtile PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "drtile" PREFIX "" SUFFIX  ".pyd")

ELSE()
    SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(drtile PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "drtile" PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".so")
ENDIF()
```

The library is compiled and linked correctly but when I look at the liked library with otool I get:

```
otool -L drtile.so

drtile.so:
/Users/lfiaschi/phd/workspace/lazyflow/lazyflow/drtile/drtile.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
vigranumpycore.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/Users/lfiaschi/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

How can I get CMake to link the drtile.so with the fullpath to vigranumpycore.so and libboost_python.dylib?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing problem with rpath rules. I think you can fix it by adding the line

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH_USE_LINK_PATH TRUE)
```

before the `PROJECT` command.

Comment: Unfortunately even though this looks like the right solution reading the documentation of CMAKE it does not have any effect. I really don't see why ...

Comment: Could it depend on the fact that vigranumpycore.so and libbost_python.dylib are installed in non system location??